# Logging independent variable flips sign of coefficient

Tags: regression, stata, logarithm

I am running a fixed effects regression with multiple IVs. One of the IVs has a negative coefficient (which is what I expect from theory) and is significant.

The Stata code would be

```
xtreg DV IV1 IV2 IV3, fe
```

However, I suspect that the relationship is not really linear, so I took the log of that IV and entered it into the regression to replace the non-logged IV.

New Stata code would be

```
xtreg DV IV1_logged IV2 IV3, fe
```

Not surprisingly the logged IV is significant as well, but the coefficient suddenly has a positive sign, which is not necessarily what theory would suggest.

Any explanations for this?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the data. Perhaps your previous result was a side-effect of outliers, now tamed by the transformation. Try a scatter plot matrix e.g. `graph matrix IV* DV`. Perhaps the theory isn't so great after all.

Comment: Seconding @NickCox, you may want to check the raw distribution (min, max) etc... of your variables? Does `IV1` vary over several orders of magnitude? And you probably want to be more conservative on your standard errors? (Eg. at least choose heteroskedastic robust standard errors)?

Comment: Thanks for those hints, but the raw distributions of all variables seem OK, no strong outliers (especially not in the variable I logged), and I was using robust standard errors (just took it out for clarity).

Comment: By logging IV1, you lose all non-positive values of IV1. Is the number of observations the same in both regressions or do you lose observations when you log? This is something you can check.